# Workbox Service Worker doesn't always intercept request

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have a basic service worker with the following rule:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /(?:https:\/\/.*)?.(js|css)/,
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(),
);
```

I've also turned on debugging with this:

```
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
});
workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.debug);
```

I've noticed that sometimes when I load my page, the request for `/js/index.js` is intercepted, but other times it isn't. When it is, I get the following console output:

[image: console output]

And at these times I can see two requests for `/js/index.js` on the network tab - one loaded from the Service Worker, and one from the network to update the SW cache.

However, at other times, that output does not appear in the console at all. Checking the network tab shows the script being loaded just once, from the Service Worker, and not being fetched from the network at all. This is quite a pain because my JS is not getting updated very frequently. It seems to get missed a lot more regularly on the phone than on the desktop (both tested with Chrome).

I seem to have some sort of race condition, but I have no clue where it's coming from. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!